# I want to write a query which name having first character having a or b or c or c-g

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a query which name having first character having `a` or `b` or `c` or `c-g`.
I have list of name with alphabetical order `A-Z`. i want to filter the by alphabetical order in 3 steps  `A-G`, `G-M`, `N-Z`.

By clicking `A-G` the record shows the name which first character starting from `A-G`

```
mysql_query("select * from users where name like "A%" or name like "B%" or name like "C%" or name like "D%" or name like "E%" or name like "F%" or name like "G%"");
```

But i don't want to write the like several time

so is there any easy way instead of writing like several time.

Comment: Old mysql extension (with it's `mysql_` functions) is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`REGEXP` could work well here:

```
SELECT ........ WHERE `name` REGEXP '^[a-g]'
```

Alternatively, to make better use of indexes:

```
... WHERE `name` < 'G'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try

```
mysql_query("select * from users where LOWER(SUBSTR(name, 1, 1)) IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')");
```

Comment: + Perhaps you can add lower(  ) at substr so you know that there are only lowers :)

Comment: @Svetlio Unless the OP specifically set their table to CS or binary, it won't matter ^_^

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to achieve this:

**First**: you can do it with `.. OR LIKE ..` syntax, like you've described.

**Second**: use [SUBSTRING()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to pass into `IN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE SUBSTRING(name, 1,1) IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

or use [ORD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ord)

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE ORD(SUBSTRING(name, 1,1)) BETWEEN ORD('A') AND ORD('C')
```

**Third**: use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE name REGEXP '^[ABC]'
```

Comment: Your regex matches everything.

Comment: Mistyped while doing all that ways :\ Thanks. Anyway, I was too late :p